# Custom imagebutton: change the image with custom selector attributes

Tags: android, resources, customization, selector, imagebutton

I wanted to change the image of my imagebuttons according to the fact, if something is in the db or not. I decided to do this via a custom selector with the attributes: empty, full, warning and alltaken.

Now when I start the MainActivity I set a call to the db and ask if it is empty or not. If not, the attributes should change from empty:true, full:false, warning:false and alltaken:false to empty:false, full:true, warning:false and alltaken:false.

My CustomImageButton class is the following:

```
public CustomImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private static final int[] STATE_EMPTY = {R.attr.state_empty};
    private static final int[] STATE_FULL = {R.attr.state_full};
    private static final int[] STATE_WARNING = {R.attr.state_warning};
    private static final int[] STATE_ALLTAKEN = {R.attr.state_alltaken};

    private boolean mIsEmpty = false;
    private boolean mIsFull = false;
    private boolean mIsWarning = false;
    private boolean mIsAlltaken = false;

    public void setEmpty(boolean isEmpty) {mIsEmpty = isEmpty;}
    public void setFull(boolean isFull) {mIsFull = isFull;}
    public void setWarning(boolean isWarning) {mIsWarning = isWarning;}
    public void setAlltaken(boolean isAlltaken) {mIsAlltaken = isAlltaken;}

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 2);
        if (mIsEmpty) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_EMPTY);
        }
        if (mIsFull) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_FULL);
        }
        if (mIsWarning) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_WARNING);
        }
        if (mIsAlltaken) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_ALLTAKEN);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }
```

And in my MainActivity I call these functions:

```
    CustomImageButton mondaybtn, tuesdaybtn, wednesdaybtn, thursdaybtn, fridaybtn, saturdaybtn, sundaybtn;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mondaybtn = (CustomImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iBtnMonday);
            tuesdaybtn = (CustomImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iBtnTuesday);
            wednesdaybtn = (CustomImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iBtnWednesday);
            thursdaybtn = (CustomImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iBtnThursday);
            fridaybtn = (CustomImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iBtnFriday);
            saturdaybtn = (CustomImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iBtnSaturday);
            sundaybtn = (CustomImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iBtnSunday);

            getDBInfo();
        }
 private void getDBInfo(){
        sqlcon = new SQLController(this);
        sqlcon.open();
        Cursor c = sqlcon.readEntry();
        int rows = c.getCount();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Rows in DB:" + String.valueOf(rows), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(rows >= 1){
            //ToDo all pictures full

            setCustomButtonImage(mondaybtn, false, true, false, false);
            setCustomButtonImage(tuesdaybtn, false, true, false, false);
            setCustomButtonImage(wednesdaybtn, false, true, false, false);
            setCustomButtonImage(thursdaybtn, false, true, false, false);
            setCustomButtonImage(fridaybtn, false, true, false, false);
            setCustomButtonImage(saturdaybtn, false, true, false, false);
            setCustomButtonImage(sundaybtn, false, true, false, false);

            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnMonday, MedListActivity.class);
            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnTuesday, MedListActivity.class);
            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnWednesday, MedListActivity.class);
            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnThursday, MedListActivity.class);
            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnFriday, MedListActivity.class);
            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnSaturday, MedListActivity.class);
            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnSunday, MedListActivity.class);
        }
        else{
            setCustomButtonImage(mondaybtn, true, false, false, false);
            setCustomButtonImage(tuesdaybtn, true, false, false, false);
            setCustomButtonImage(wednesdaybtn, true, false, false, false);
            setCustomButtonImage(thursdaybtn, true, false, false, false);
            setCustomButtonImage(fridaybtn, true, false, false, false);
            setCustomButtonImage(saturdaybtn, true, false, false, false);
            setCustomButtonImage(sundaybtn, true, false, false, false);

            //ToDo all pictures empty
            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnMonday, EnterMedActivity.class);
            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnTuesday, EnterMedActivity.class);
            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnWednesday, EnterMedActivity.class);
            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnThursday, EnterMedActivity.class);
            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnFriday, EnterMedActivity.class);
            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnSaturday, EnterMedActivity.class);
            setDisplayViewButtonClickListener(R.id.iBtnSunday, EnterMedActivity.class);
        }
    }

    private void setCustomButtonImage(CustomImageButton btn,Boolean empty, Boolean full, Boolean warning,Boolean alltaken){

        btn.setEmpty(empty);
        btn.setFull(full);
        btn.setWarning(warning);
        btn.setAlltaken(alltaken);
    }
```

In drawables I have files like this for the selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dailymeds="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        dailymeds:state_empty="true"
        dailymeds:state_full="false"
        dailymeds:state_warning="false"
        dailymeds:state_alltaken="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/emptyshapefriday" />

    <item
        dailymeds:state_empty="true"
        dailymeds:state_full="false"
        dailymeds:state_warning="false"
        dailymeds:state_alltaken="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/demptyshapefriday" />

    <item
        dailymeds:state_full="true"
        dailymeds:state_empty="false"
        dailymeds:state_warning="false"
        dailymeds:state_alltaken="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/fullshapefriday" />

    <item
        dailymeds:state_full="true"
        dailymeds:state_empty="false"
        dailymeds:state_warning="false"
        dailymeds:state_alltaken="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/dfullshapefriday" /> ....
```

And I also have the needed resources file in res/values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="dailymeds">

        <attr name="state_empty" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="state_full" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="state_warning" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="state_alltaken" format="boolean" />


    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Why is the image not changing even if i change the empty, full, warning and alltaken attributes?